# ExactTarget Conversion Tracking issues

Tags: marketing-cloud, conversion

I am working with a script to collect conversions and pass into ExactTarget for reporting. For some reason the conversion is not tracking back to ExactTarget even though there are no errors:

```
document.write("<img src='");
document.write("https://click.s6.exacttarget.com/conversion.aspx?xml=<system><system_name>tracking</system_name><action>conversion</action>");
document.write("<member_id><$MISC4></member_id>");
document.write("<job_id><$MISC1></job_id>");
document.write("<email><$MISC3></email>");
document.write("<list>0</list>");
document.write("<BatchID><$MISC2></BatchID>");
document.write("<original_link_id>0</original_link_id>");
document.write("<conversion_link_id>0</conversion_link_id>");
document.write("<link_alias>"+linkalias+"</link_alias>");
document.write("<display_order>"+displayorder+"</display_order>");
document.write("<data_set>"+dataset+"</data_set>");
document.write("</system>'");
document.write(" width='1' height='1'>");
```

Below is what would populate:

```
<img src='https://click.s6.exacttarget.com/conversion.aspx?xml=<system><system_name>tracking</system_name><action>conversion</action><member_id>6293159</member_id><job_id>523034</job_id><email>MyEmail@thisisatestemail.com</email><list>0</list><BatchID>1</BatchID><original_link_id>0</original_link_id><conversion_link_id>0</conversion_link_id><link_alias>My Link Name</link_alias><display_order>1</display_order><data_set><data amt="19.98" unit="Dollars" accumulate="true" type="Subscription" /></data_set></system>' width='1' height='1'>
```

Any ideas why this is not tracking the conversion on ExactTarget's end?
Thanks
Ben

Answer (score 2):

Have you included conversion="true" in the appropriate links in your email campaign or landing page links?

http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/tracking/conversion_tracking/implement_conversion_tracking/insert_the_link_in_your_email/

That would be required to track legacy email conversions/revenue within the typical "Tracking" tabs.

You may also wish to explore "new" conversion tracking via Discover and Web & Mobile Analytics in order to get email revenue attribution, but note at this time it does require a services engagement with SFMC to complete the implementation.

http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/discover/email_revenue_attribution/